# Getting Error when running 'ng test' Command

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Error: Template parse errors:
'router-outlet' is not a known element:
1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/AppComponent.html@0:0

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Just add the line :

```
imports: [RouterTestingModule],
```

in `TestBed.configureTestingModule` of your **components spec.ts** file and

```
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
```

Like:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [RouterTestingModule],
  declarations: [ ComponentHeaderComponent ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding RouterTestingModule in imports array will do your work.

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [RouterTestingModule],
  .
  .
  .
});